# Dynamically combining 'preset' layouts

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm trying to dynamically place different metabolic pathways (nodes following a preset layout contained in a parent node).

Normally i would define positions for each child node, so as to not overlap the parent nodes. However the graphs( = generated json containing the requested nodes) are generated dynamically, so this is not an option.

Is there a way to achieve this, short of recalculating positions for each node as the json is being generated.

**E.g.: requesting glycolysis -> TCA -> Urea**

[Current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srqkW.png)

[Acceptable solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeC7M.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do something manual like that you'll probably have to use some code rather than just specify a layout.

```
let shiftPosition = (pos, delta) => ({ x: pos.x + delta.x, y: pos.y + delta.y });
let shiftNode = (node, delta) => shiftPosition( node.position(), delta );
let findDelta = parent => ({ x: 100, y: 100 }); // determine yourself

cy.nodes(':parent').forEach( parent => {
  let delta = findDelta( parent );

  parent.children().positions( node => shiftNode( node, delta ) );
} );
```